# SSIS - Package execution stop

Tags: ssis

I have an issue that is bothering me, and I was thinking maybe someone might be able to help.

The thing is, I have a project made up by multiple packages that are executed within a master package.

When i run the master package, the execution begins, but when it hits the first package that it needs to execute, it just stops.

The output shows me the following things:

> SSIS package "Master_Package.dtsx" starting.
>
> SSIS package "Master_Package.dtsx" finished: Canceled.

If i enter that package and run the data flow in it, it works perfectly, but if i run the entire master package, or i just execute that package alone within the master package page, it just stops.

Any help would be gladly appreciated. 
Thank you for your time!

Calin

Answer (score 0):

Silly and obvious question: Are you using the execute package task on your master package? If so, are you referencing the right child package at the correct location?

It is a straight forward call from Master to Child even if you are passing parameters within the packages and should be no reason for child package to abend unless you are not calling it correctly.

Comment: Yes, the reference is right.
I've tried 2 options. One with the packages referenced from the SQL Database, which has the behaviour mentioned above, and one with the packages referenced from the local file system. The second option works fine, but i need the packages to load from the SQL, to simulate the production environment.